# Code to execute when ActiveWorkbook.Connections("x").Refresh is finished

Tags: sql-server, excel, remote-connections, vba

**select data from external source**
I have a data connection that retreives data using a `select` query from SQL-server into an Excel sheet using vba code like this:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("x"). _
    OLEDBConnection
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .CommandText = Array( _
    "SELECT ... FROM ...
...
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("x").Refresh
```

**linked pivot table to imported data needs to be refreshed as well**
However as far as I can tell `ActiveWorkbook.Connections("x").Refresh` runs asynchonious and I want to execute code that runs after the refresh has finished, so that I can run this code:

```
Private Sub UpdatePivot()
Dim PV As PivotItem

  For Each PV In ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PT1").PivotFields("PN").PivotItems
    If PV.Name <> "(blank)" Then
      PV.Visible = True
    Else
      PV.Visible = False
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

**but only when the data is read in**
How do I know when the refresh is done getting all the data?
What do I have to do to only run the `UpdatePivot` sub after the Refresh is complete without resorting to `sleep` hacks.

*P.S. Sometimes the query is fast (<1 sec), sometimes it's slow (> 30 sec) depending on the exact data i'm selecting, which is dynamic.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a brilliant solution, but you could make `ActiveWorkbook.Connections("x").Refresh` run synchronously by setting

```
.BackgroundQuery = False
```

Another more complex solution would be to poll the status of the connection by checking the [`.Refreshing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.oledbconnection.refreshing.aspx) property inside a loop construct.

Comment: Need an example of .refreshing property.

Answer (score 1):

`.BackgroundQuery = False` will NOT ensure synchronous execution following the data refresh.

Try it yourself by creating a simple query and in the Worksheet_Change subroutine add code to select a few cells.  I can often get 2 commands to fire before the waiting/timeout circle appears.

Thus I cannot determine if the query has returned the right data.  I have tried setting a reference cell to the value of a mid query column and checked that the two are equal - unfortunately the `Worksheet_Change` event FIRES TWICE UPON DATA REFRESH!

This is driving me crazy.  I just need to go print a chart after successful query refresh.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects(1).QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```